# Export data to Access from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export

I am brand new to access and struggling to understand how to relate access table/column/row formatting to excel exporting in VBA.

I have created an access table called *Data* and three columns *Food, Drinks, Color*.

[image: Access Table]

I would like to export these range of cells to Access from my excel spreadsheet:

```
Foodrng = Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("D6")
Drinksrng = Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("E6")
Colorrng= Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("B12:B21")
```

Everything online says I should use this for because of my version:

```
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
```

I would like to use `INSERT TO` formatting to write to my database because I will be expanding the database columns quite a bit, and I feel this is the easiest way to keep track of which is going where.

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO Data (Food, Drinks, Color) VALUES (Foodrng, Drinksrng,Colorrng)"
```

I always get a syntax error when executing:

```
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
```

What is the correct way to export to the Access database using the above method? Any/all information will be super helpful as I am brand new to Access

**My full code:**

```
    Foodrng = Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("D6")
    Drinksrng = Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("E6")
    Colorrng= Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("B12:B21")

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source= C:\Users\User1\MyDBase.accdb"
    cn.Open strConnection

   strSql = "INSERT INTO Data (Food, Drinks, Color) VALUES (Foodrng, Drinksrng,Colorrng)"

    Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
    'MsgBox rs.Fields(0) & " rows in MyTable"
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm not too good with SQL but maybe you need to pass the variable's reference instead of the literal string? `strSql = "INSERT INTO Data (Food, Drinks, Color) VALUES (" & Foodrng & ", " & Drinksrng & ", " & Colorrng & ")"`  (You may also try `Foodrng.Address` if it doesn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting using queries, you need to pass values using parameters. I highly recommend using recordsets over insert queries.

A normal insert query can only insert one row at a time. You will need to adjust the code to insert one row at a time. You can either use a recordset, or execute a query for each row.

```
Foodrng = Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("D6") 'Adjust ranges to select single cells
Drinksrng = Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("E6")
Colorrng= Workbooks(xlFile).Sheets("ToBeExported").Range("B12:B21")

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source= C:\Users\User1\MyDBase.accdb"
cn.Open strConnection

strSql = "INSERT INTO [Data] ([Food], [Drinks], [Color]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = strSql
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarWChar, adParamInput, , foodRng) 'adVarWChar for text 
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , Drinksrng) 'adInteger for whole numbers (long or integer)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , Colorrng)
    .Execute
End With
cn.Close
```

Comment: @Parfait Nope, that doesn't work and that's why the code comment _Adjust ranges to select single cells_. The proper way is to use a recordset and iterate through the cells. Or even better: import from Access instead of exporting from Excel. That way, you can customize more easily.

Comment: @Parfait I guess that's true. Added clarification.

Comment: Compile error: User defined type not defined.   This happenes on the first AND second cmd variable

Comment: Set a reference to ADO (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects) if you want to use ADO. Doing this all with late bindings is unnecesarily hard.

Comment: I will have multiple users with different versions of access (Therefore different library versions).  Wont using early binding cause unwanted issues?

Comment: Usually, no. Multiple versions of ADO get installed with Access to avoid compatibility issues. But feel free to convert it yourself to late bindings. Be aware that you need to convert all those enums too.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.  When adding in ADO reference, I now get a run-time error '424' (object required) on the .parameters.append line.

Comment: What values correspond to where the "?, ?, ?"  are in the strSql string?  I am under the impression they are the access table rows?   The eddited version works now until the .exectue line (Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement).  I am assuming it has to do with what I stated above?

Comment: They're markers that get replaced by the parameters when you execute the query.

Comment: Ok, so they should be left as "?".  Any idea why the edited version errors on the .execute line (Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement)?

Comment: One of your field names or your table name is likely a keyword. Try the current edit.

Comment: That was it!  Huge thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If one of my cells does not contain a value, then I receive parameter ?_7 has no default value.  Where 7 is the 7th "?" being filled in.   Is there a way for access to accept blank values?

Comment: You can use `adEmpty` instead of `adVarWChar` to specify that a parameter doesn't contain a value

Comment: `adEmpty` doesn't seem to be working,  Is there an ADO data type that accepts values no matter what?  The values of cells I am submitting are not always integers, there sometimes text, and sometimes blank.  For example, cell "A1" may start as an integer, then the next time around it will be blank.

Comment: You should use the appropriate type for the field in Access. There's no field that can accept all that in Access.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe also another way, or two, perhaps worth consideration.

The first would be to set up your Excel spreadsheet as a linked table in Access - maybe it can be done with VBA. This would save you the requirement to copy the data. You might also be able to set up your target worksheet and use insert..select directly from ADODB to insert the data into Excel from Access.

The second, would be to completely avoid Access altogether if your requirements allow for this. Excel can be used as a database to some extent and supports SQL querying.
https://selectcompare.com/blogs/news/write-select-statements-for-excel-spreadsheets